# Historical data and measures Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-platform

I have a report in PowerBI let's name it `report.pbix` for example, containing some graphs.

Each time the user wants to show the graphs, he changes the source of the data (an Excel file with always the same structure) and click refresh. The graphs are updated with the new data and measures calculated.

My question is, it is possible to stock or get a part from the previous Excel file or the previous source? Does PowerBI have the ability to store data from the previous sources?

Because I want to show some historic evolution.

Or will I need to use a separate technology to achieve such a thing?

Comment: Power BI doesn't store/persist data between refreshes. You will need to load both Excel files in the PBI for it to compare. For example you could have PBI load in all Excel files in a folder, and then your users simply need to add the required Excel file in that folder.